# Can a Castle DynamicProxy-generated proxy be forced to implement members as explicit interface implementations?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, mixins, castle-dynamicproxy

For example, let's say I've defined an interface as follows:

```
public interface IWhatever
{
     string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And I implement it in a mixin:

```
public class WhateverMixin : IWhatever
{
     string IWhatever.Text { get; set; }
}
```

When I build a proxy of some given class, the whole explicitly-implemented interface member appears as implicitly implemented so it gets *published*.

Do you know if there's some option I can give to Castle DynamicProxy to force implementing an interface with explicit implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, DynamicProx doesn't seem to have any options for this. There's no such setting in the `ProxyGenerationOptions` or `MixinData` classes, and if you look into the code (starting from `MixinContributor`, which leads to [`MethodGenerator`](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/src/Castle.Core/DynamicProxy/Generators/MethodGenerator.cs#L48)), you can see that it simply copies the name and attributes (visibility, etc.) from the interface method.

Comment: Just curious... Do you know any other proxy generator that has already implemented such feature?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know of any other proxy generators, although you could probably use the [TypePipe](http://typepipe.codeplex.com/) to build your own. Alternatively, if you just need mixin capabilities, you could try re-motion's [re-mix](https://remix.codeplex.com/)  - that library implements mixin interfaces explicitly by default. (Note that I'm one of the original authors of both of these libraries.)

Comment: Well, actually another alternative would be using IL weaving with PostSharp. At the end of the day, if you want to know what's the backgorund of this Q&A... it's because of some open source I've been developing during last year: http://matiasfidemraizer.com/trackerdog

Comment: It's a generic change tracking library for .NET. And I'm asking this question because of the following issue contributed by some user: https://github.com/mfidemraizer/trackerdog/issues/10